# Nuxt 3 won't run after importing composition api module

Tags: vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I just started a fresh project with Nuxt 3. Installed only Sass and tailwind packages, everything worked fine. Then I added composition-api and it didn't start anymore. Can't find any fixes on this issue.

```
buildModules: [
  '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module',
]
```

then when I run 'npm run dev':

> ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'resolveModule')                     14:27:08
>
> at Object.compositionApiModule2
> (node_modules@nuxtjs\composition-api\dist\module\index.js:124:85)

Does someone here have an idea on how to fix? I already tried removing node modules and package.lock and reinstalling, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuxt 3 does not need the `@nuxtjs/composition-api` module. You can just use the composition api as you know it from Vue 3.

A short TypeScript example of the composition api in Nuxt 3:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>

onMounted(() => {
  console.log("Hello World!");
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: Might work (it also does in my case) but it feels hack-ish since VSCode does not recognize '#imports' as a valid module, so will show red squiggly lines under it. Additionally it also does not show intellisense.

Comment: @Falgantil the #imports import should not be a requirement, you should be able to use the onMounted function without having to import anything.